# ByteBuddy - Rebasing native methods

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm checking if I can use ByteBuddy to replace some bulky ASM code with a smaller, more elegant solution. One part is to "wrap" native methods, meaning prefix any existing native method in a class and provide a new, non-native method with the same name and signature calling the prefixed one. All this can happen during build time, so I don't need any agents, neither need to worry about potential class schema changes, etc

From the documentation it seemed like a case for rebasing where ByteBuddy leaves a copy of the original method and provides the possibilty to call it via `@SuperCall`.

Besides not being able to influence the new names for the original methods (they need to have a prefix, not a postfix) the following code leads to the error below:

```
        new ByteBuddy()
        .rebase(typePool.describe("test.ClassWithNatives").resolve(), ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.ofClassPath())
        .method(named("someNativeMethod"))
        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(NativeInterceptor.class))
        .make()
        .load(getClass().getClassLoader())
        .getLoaded();
```

.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error invoking java.lang.ClassLoader#findClass
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Direct.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:410)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection.inject(ClassInjector.java:183)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$InjectionDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:187)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:120)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:79)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4376)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4366)
    at ByteBuddyTest.wrapNatives(ByteBuddyTest.java:45)
    at ByteBuddyTest.start(ByteBuddyTest.java:22)
    at ByteBuddyTest.main(ByteBuddyTest.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file ClassWithNatives
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Direct.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:406)
    ... 9 more
```

Is it possible to realize such a scenario with ByteBuddy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only possible by using a Java agent via an `Instrumentation`. Otherwise, the JVM does not know how to rebase a native method which has native adapters that have to follow method naming conventions. For Byte Buddy to work, the original code is moved to a different method for being invokable from the original method which is not possible otherwise.

Using a Java agent, it is possible to run:

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
  .enableNativeMethodPrefix("foo")
  .type(named("test.ClassWithNatives"))
  .transform((b,t,c,m) -> b
    .method(named("someNativeMethod"))
    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(NativeInterceptor.class))
  ).installOn(inst);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but for me this leads to the same error. I enhanced the lambda to get the `ReceiverTypeDefinition` and saved the `byte[]` in a file before returning the definition. From the byte code I saw that the `native` flag is removed from the class' modifier list, but no code to the `Interceptor` is added. Also no renamed native method exists (besides that the native method prefix handed to ByteBuddy seems to be only used to be set on the instrumentation but does not really influence how ByteBuddy generates the new method names, does it?)

Comment: You are right, I just found a bug here which I am resolving in the version 1.6.6. I will push it in the next hours.

Comment: Nice, I just retested. Works with the agent now! Also via `new ByteBuddy()` the native method is now intercepted correctly, just that I obviously can't call the original method because it is not prefixed. Not sure if it would break the architecture but would it be so "wrong" to have something like `new ByteBuddy().enableNativeMethodPrefix("prefix")` ? Also I would appreciate if you could share some insights on how the prefixed native actually is called now as I couldn't find a native method using `javap`, just an `invokestatic` it. But where is the method defined now?

Comment: The native method prefix is dispatched via Java's `Instrumentation` interface which `ByteBuddy` instances do not interact with directly. By only prefixing the rebased method (which is possible via the overloaded `rebase` methods), the native methods are not longer bound correctly as their name has changed. Therefore, the prefix has be bound via instrumentation.

Comment: What I meant is that I can't see a native method in the transformed class at all. I can see the rebased one with the original name which is not native anymore, (as expected) but I can't find the new native method with the prefix in the name. The only thing I see is an invokestatic instruction to a method with the prefixed name (which is also as expected). But using javap there is simply no native method showing up anymore in the transformed class. Nevertheless it is working somehow, but I really don't get what the jvm is calling if no native is in the bytecode. What am I missing?

Comment: Btw, my understanding on native resolution is based on this so far: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#setNativeMethodPrefix-java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer-java.lang.String- . This implies, however, that there is a new native method with the prefix in the name. This is what I'm missing in the transformed class. Or is javap simply not showing it? It shows other natives and synthetic methods though.

Comment: Are you using the verbose switch? The rebased method is private.

Comment: Afff... that was it. Actually I was using only verbose, but I needed `-private` as well. Just verbose does not show privates and I missed the part that the rebased methods do not keep the same visibility. Thanks a lot!